# Using ntohs() with stringstream

Tags: c++

I have a question on how to use `ntohs()` when I am reading data from `stringstream`.

For the following code:

```
read(ns, buf_receive, BUFFER_SIZE);

stringstreams ss(buf_receive);
char[2] a;
short int b;

ss << a[0] << a[1];
ss << b;

cout >> b;
```

My issue lies with that my data format recieved is not purely `short`. So I cannot put this function directly onto `buf_receive`, like so: `ntohs(buf_receive)`, nor can I use it onto `b`, like so: `ntohs(b)`.

So is there a good way (without resorting to manually shifting the bits) to implement this?

Comment: Wrong site: this belongs on Stack Overflow.

Comment: There are many more people reading SO. You will get a better answer there.

Answer (score 1):

You could always create a class that contains a `short`, then define custom `operator>>` and `operator<<` to read/write the value from the stream, which handle the byte ordering by calling `ntohs` and `htons` respectively.

Then, replace the usage of `short` in your example with your new class type.

As its homework, I won't provide an implementation.